# Can't find rake on Ruby Rails Install

Tags: ruby, rake

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>gem install rake
Successfully installed rake-0.8.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.8.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.8.7...

C:\Windows\system32>rake
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': can
't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Why can't my system find the rake command? Where should I start debugging the problem?

**Update 1**

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and installed it using the ruby installer for windows (http://rubyinstaller.org/)

Comment: what installer did you use? what ruby version and patch number did you install? run "ruby --version" to get the exact version and patch number

Comment: The *eleventh* line reveals the problem, for anyone who knows even the slightest bit about Ruby and doesn't just hang out on StackOverflow to make stupid snarky comments that stopped being funny 20 years ago.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This issue is a problem of Ruby 1.9.2 bundled version of Rake. You will need to remove the included `rake.gemspec` from the gem specification folder.

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/9817d0c6c8a48a79) at RubyInstaller group, and specifically [this link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/214757#932314) from Ruby-Forums for the solution.

BTW: a recommendation: avoid installing Ruby into path with spaces (Program Files). I forsee lot of problems with your installation in the future.

Comment: I had the same problem, even though my path to ruby does not include spaces; fortunately deleting rake.gemspec helped. Thanks!

Comment: The path with spaces will bring other type of issues, not the one originally asked (free advice would you say) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install Ruby (or RubyGems) in a path with whitespace.

Comment: i had suspicion of this, but didn't have a change to try it out before i saw your answer. good to know. :)

Comment: A workaround is to use the short file name for the directory. E.g. "C:\Program Files\" will be "C:\PROGRA~1\". Obtainable from the command line using `dir "C:\Long Directory Name" /X`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your PATH like?  Run the following command.

```
echo %PATH%
```

Ruby on Windows is very tricky.  It's not exactly designed for something like this.  There are three major ways people get Ruby installed.  First, they download straight binaries and try to hack together something workable.  Second, they use the old one-click installer.  Third, they use the new [Ruby installer](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/ss/Installing-A-Ruby-Development-Environment-On-Windows.htm).  If you have *anything else*, get rid of it and go with the third option.